# Custom Delete command does nor mark every row for deletion in MVC Kendo.Grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo.Grid() with a custom command and its `Click` event where I need to mark columns for deletion.

When clicking on the button, only odd rows are marked.

This is logic:

Grid's Custom column:

`columns.Command(c => c.Custom("Delete").Click("DeleteRecord"));`

`DeleteRecord` function:

```
function DeleteRecord(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var grid = $("#MyGrid").getKendoGrid();
    var row = $(e.target).closest("tr"),
        dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
    dataItem.deleted = true;
    row.addClass("deleted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by setting the `background-color` attribute to red:

`row.css("background-color", "red");`